# Value of PHP variables not transferring with include statement

Tags: php, variables, include

OK, I know that I am being stupid about this, but I can't seem to figure out how I am being so.

I have variables for social media links in a separate .php file so that my client can change them without having to see too much code.

I include that .php file in my normal code where I want the links to be. But, for some reason the value of the variable is not being transmitted. I even tried to make a "global" variable. Here is my code.

File: socialMediaURLs.php

```
<?php

    global $facebook = 'https://www.facebook.com/MenCoachingMen'; 
    $googlePlus = 'https://plus.google.com/104275309033865331192/posts';
    $twitter = 'https://twitter.com/MenCoachingMen';
    $rss = 'http://mencoachingmen.org/category/podcast/feed/';
    $vimeo = 'https://vimeo.com/mencoachingmen';
    $youtube = 'https://www.youtube.com/channel/UCy_Pth5x-O7rcX9nMx1e8qw';

?>
```

File: socialLinks.php

```
<?php include './socialMediaURLs.php'; ?>

<div class="social_links_wrapper">

    <a href="<?php echo $facebook;?>">
        <div class="sl_facebook">
            <i class="fa fa-facebook fa-5x"></i>
        </div>
    </a>

    <a href="<?php echo $googlePlus;?>">
        <div class="sl_googlePlus">
            <i class="fa fa-google-plus fa-5x"></i>
        </div>
    </a>    

    <a href="<?php echo $twitter;?>">
        <div class="sl_twitter">
            <i class="fa fa-twitter fa-5x"></i>
        </div>
    </a>

    <a href="<?php echo $rss;?>">
        <div class="sl_rss">
            <i class="fa fa-rss fa-5x"></i>
        </div>
    </a>

    <a href="<?php echo $vimeo;?>">
        <div class="sl_vimeo">
            <i class="fa fa-vimeo-square fa-5x"></i>
        </div>
    </a>

    <a href="<?php echo $youtube;?>">
        <div class="sl_youtube">
            <i class="fa fa-youtube fa-5x"></i>
        </div>
    </a>

</div>
```

I ran a test like so:

```
<?php 
    if($facebook){
        echo $facebook;
    }else{
        echo 'Facebook NULL';
    }
?>
```

I put this after the `include` statement and before the rest of the code. And it prints out 'Facebook NULL'. So, I know that the value is not being transmitted. Now, if I put in the included .php file (where the variables are stored) a `echo "Hello World!";` line, "Hello World!" does print out on the screen. So, I know that the file is being included correctly (ie the path is correct).

I then placed this code after the 'include' and before the rest of the code:

```
$facebook = 'https://www.facebook.com/MenCoachingMen';
```

When I do that, the URL is included within the page. So, I know that my php statements within the code is correct. That means that it has to be a transmission of the value of the variable after including it. Please help. I know this must be a stupid mistake somewhere. Thank you.

Comment: The `global` keyword is only used inside functions, it allows the function to access global variables. Variables assigned outside a function are automatically global (what other scope would they be in)?

Comment: Do you have error reporting on? You might find out the path to the included file is wrong.

Comment: @KaiQing If the path were wrong, how would `echo "Hellow World!"` work?

Comment: In the include file, the assignments aren't inside a function, are they?

Comment: There has to be more than you're showing us. This is too trivial to fail.

Comment: Aah, I didn't bother reading to the hello world part

Comment: Thank you @Barmar, I thought it was too trivial to fail. And I can't figure out what the issue is. You are correct in that the path is correct. And the assignments are not in a function, to answer your question.

Comment: Ok, so here is the whole of it, if it makes more sense.

This is being used in a WordPress theme. The links are in a file that is accessible in the backend 'Editor' area so that the client can gain quick access to it. 

In the WordPress theme below the navigation area I call the .php file with my code. like so. `include './wp-content/sitewideCode/socialLinks.php';` Then, within that file is the information I included above. 

I don't think that any of that information should change the matter though. And I included all code in both the files to you all.

Comment: Here is the live page with the code being displayed: http://staticchurch.com/

Comment: There's no way for us to tell what's going on in PHP by looking at the resulting page. You need to check the PHP error log on the server, something must be failing.

Comment: Ok, the error log shows that it is failing to open the file... but the "Hello World!" test works fine. How can it fail to open a file but still open it and run an echo? Am I reading this error wrong?

`Failed opening 'http://staticchurch.com/wp-content/themes/MenCoachingMen/socialMediaURLs.php' for inclusion `

And I was using the live page as an example to show that the "Hello World!" test was working.

Comment: I just reset the error_log and refreshed the page a few times. This error is no longer showing up in the log. I do not believe it is valid any longer/ is no longer an issue.

Comment: I am calling it. This is happening for an unknown reason and is not worth the headache. I am just going to move all the code from the file "socialMediaURLs.php" to the very top of the file "socialLinks.php" and do away with the include statement all together. My client should be able to see where to edit the URLs easily enough. Thank you @Barmar and KaiQing for offering assistance. I will leave this question open in case someone else later on sees an issue.

Answer (score 0):

A global variable must be used inside a function.

```
function name(){
    global $globalvar = "some info";
}
```

to pass a variable OUT of it and into the script. You can't pass variables to other scripts using global variables. Consider using $_SESSION['name'] variables to pass variables from script to script.

http://php.net/manual/en/book.session.php

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php include 'socialMediaURLs.php'; ?> <--- top main public_html/www
<?php include 'directory1/socialMediaURLs.php'; ?> <-- one folder deep
<?php include 'directory1/directory2/socialMediaURLS.php'; ?> <-- two folders deep

//calling a file FROM two folders deep TO A FILE IN the root folder!    
<?php include('../../socialMediaURLS.php'; ?>  <--- main index public_html/www
//ETC......
<?php include('../../directory1/socialMediaURLS.php'; ?>
```

I hope this helps. Think of it like DIR and CD commands.